# Upload image not work on production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, paperclip, passenger

Upload image work good on my machine but not work on live server.

This is params on localhost:

```
{"provider_source"=>{"photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa23410 @original_filename="som_statenisland_netzero_school.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"provider_source[photos_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"som_statenisland_netzero_school.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121129-4550-xbzsif>>, "description"=>""}, "1"=>{"description"=>""}, "2"=>{"description"=>""}}}, "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6cMwEI4lZreocgiOyJRdDfh2cGMcs85i28mMdsEWvog=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01"}
```

I installed image magick on live server.

I use nginx + Phusion Passenger for my application on live server.

On Live server I choose a image and hit submit. the image params always is nil.

Here is my nginx config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root /srv/www/rails/bbz_dev;
        passenger_enabled on;

        }
}
```

I don't know why it's occurs this problem. I try to solved it 2 days but I can't. Please help me a way to solved this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

in production.rb, do you have this ?

```
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

Comment: Ok, can you paste in your question your nginx config file ?

Comment: Mhh, i see you're using passenger, can't help you with that. I remember i had problem with it so I now use unicorn with nginx and upload works flawlessly with the line in my answer.